# Socket IO iOS sdk confuses xCode

Tags: swift, xcode, socket.io

installed socket.io sdk using cocoapods:

```
pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift'
```

Once I import it

```
import SocketIO
```

I get this weird warning and whenever I run the app it crashes:
[image]

item is referred as the following:

```
func createChatBox(item: AnyObject) -> UIView {
    message.text = (item["message"] as! String)
}
```

And called as the following:

```
createChatBox(item: messages[0] as AnyObject)
```

Where

```
var messages:[Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] = [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]()
```

With declaration

```
messages = [["type": 1 as AnyObject, "message"  : "Hello" as AnyObject]]
```

Everything works fine without import SocketIO, I don't really know what is the problem with SocketIO and my variables.

Also, accessing the data directly without my functions works fine, as the following:

```
print(messages[0]["message"] as! String)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that